# Unable to drop to another columns react beautiful dnd

Tags: reactjs

I successfully drag and drop inside the column but I am not able to drop another column. It doesn't give any error but when I log the console I see the destination is null. What do I need to do?[image]

Comment: please add sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for debugging.